# I have a broken while loop in c

Tags: c

I am writing a small c program where the user must insert a product code (ex: i), where it then asks the users desired quantity. The while loop will only exit when user inputs x value.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

   // Variables & initialisations
   char type = ' ';
   int quantity = 0;
   int iCount = 0, oCount = 0, pCount = 0, bCount = 0; //Product counts
   int iCost = 0, oCost = 0, pCost = 0, bCost = 0;
   int totalCost = 0;

   printf("------ The White Paint Shop -----\n\n");
   printf("Products: i = Indoor paint\n");
   printf("          o = Outdoor paint\n");
   printf("          p = Primer\n");
   printf("          b = Brush\n\n");
   printf("Enter x to exit\n\n");

   printf("Enter product: ");
   scanf("%c", &type);
   type = getchar();

   while(type != 'x')
   {
       if(type = 'i')
       {
           printf("Enter quantity: ");
           scanf("%d", &quantity);

           iCount += quantity;
       }

       printf("Enter product: ");
       scanf("%c", &type);
   }

   return 0;
   }
```

However, the while loop doesn't wait for the second user input before it asks for the quantity. How can I fix this?

```
Products: i = Indoor paint       
      o = Outdoor paint
      p = Primer       
      b = Brush        

Enter x to exit

Enter product: i
Enter quantity: 23
Enter product: Enter quantity:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you should pay attention even if user first input be `'x'` it will always convert to `'\n'` and you will always enter `while` look:

```
   scanf("%c", &type);
   type = getchar();
```

because first you took a char as `type` ,but then with this line `type = getchar();` you will assign what is in buffer to `type` which means even if `x` was entered you will enter the loop.(so remove this `type = getchar();`)

second in this line `if(type = 'i')` you are assigning `'i'` to `type` not checking if `type` is `'i'`.it should be `if(type == 'i')`.

and here add a space to `scanf` like this `scanf(" %c", &type);`,otherwise it will take what is in buffer as input.(note this will be enough when you remove mentioned `getchar()`)

look

```
   scanf("%c", &type);
//remove getchar
   while(type != 'x')
   {
       if(type == 'i')//== not =
       {
           printf("Enter quantity: ");
           scanf("%d", &quantity);

           iCount += quantity;
       }

       printf("Enter product: ");
       scanf(" %c", &type);//add space
   }
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked! I forgot the assignment there. I assume the space in scan(" %c", &type)  is to ignore the new line input?

Comment: @Constalation yes space do that. and there is no need for thanks , but if this answer was helpful accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This statement needs to be corrected:

```
 if(type = 'i')
```

To read:

```
   if(type == 'i')
```

I believe that it is just a typo on your part, but if don't understand the different you can read about it here: [= versus == in c](https://www.includehelp.com/c-programming-questions/what-is-difference-between-assignment-and-equalto-operator.aspx)

I would also suggest changing:

```
scanf("%c", &type);
```

to

```
scanf("%s", type); //you can use scanf without "&" when assigning to a string
```

In order to stop duplicate print outs. However, make sure you are handling the size of possible inputs into that variable.